# How to convert Collection<Number> to Collection<Integer> safety?

Tags: java, collections, numbers, integer

I have `Collection<Number>`  but I needed `Collection<Integer>`

How can I  convert it safety?

And more common issue:

How to convert `Collection<Parent>` to `Collection<Child>`

Comment: `foreach` loop or Guava `Collections2.transform(collection, function)`.

Comment: ... or start using Java 8 Early Access :) `in.stream().map(n->n.intValue()).collect(intoList());`

Comment: **Arnaud Denoyelle** what I need to write in function?

Comment: @gstackoverflow You need a Guava Function : http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html

Comment: **Arnaud Denoyelle**,I would very glad if you write code example.

Comment: @gstackoverflow I made an answer with the guava solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) :

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;

Collection<Number> collection = ...
return Collections2.transform(collection, new Function<Number, Integer>() {
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public Integer apply(@Nullable Number input) {
    if(input == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return input.intValue();
  }
});
```

Note : Guava is an external lib, you will need to import it it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
    Collection<Number> numbers = ...
    Collection<Integer> integers = numbers.getClass().newInstance();
    for(Number n : numbers) {
        integers.add(n == null ? null : n.intValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with something like this convert method -

```
public static Collection<Integer> convert(Collection<Number> in) {
  List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (Number n : in) {
    if (n != null) {
      al.add(n.intValue());
    }
  }
  return al;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof` operator.Try this

```
Iterator<Number> itr = collection.iterator();
 while(itr.hasNext()) 
 {
       Number number = itr.next();
       if(number instanceof Integer)
       {
             Integer value = (Integer)number ;
             System.out.print("Integer is "+value );
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each loop to iterate the collection having any numeric data type and then individually insert converting those numeric data types into Integer one's into another collection.

```
List<Integer> i =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (Number n : in){
i.add(n.intValue()); 
}}
```